# Optimizing building matrix using javascript (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix

I have built a Javascript function to build a matrix ... The function is about extracting the data from a given matrix where :

- The matrix[0][i] represents dates
- And I want to extract data where matrix[0][i] is between the date1 and date2 
  as follow :

:

```
function extractDatafromMatrix(matrix, date1, date2) {

    var matrix_result = [[], [], [], []];
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {

        if (isInPeriod(date1, date2, matrix[0][i])) {
            matrix_result[0][j] = matrix[0][i];
            matrix_result[1][j] = matrix[1][i];
            matrix_result[2][j] = matrix[2][i];
            matrix_result[3][j] = matrix[3][i];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    return matrix_result;
}
```

Is there any function that can optimize the folowing part of code?

```
        matrix_result[0][j] = matrix[0][i];
        matrix_result[1][j] = matrix[1][i];
        matrix_result[2][j] = matrix[2][i];
        matrix_result[3][j] = matrix[3][i];
        j = j + 1;
```

Because I found that this assignation very ugly!  (Im using jQuery for your information)

Thank you very much

Comment: Add a for loop inside if statement?

Comment: j an i are equal? Can you explain the mapping a bit further, for me it seems that you just need to filter all from the matrix which are not in a defined date period - but there is no "remapping" or did I miss something?

Comment: If I can do something like : matrix_result[][j] = matrix[][i]; (to say assigne the indexes [0,1,2,3]) it will be wonderfull! however JS is not like Matlab

Comment: No j and i are not equals ... yes I want to filter  the original matrix to have a matrix_result

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z6sm4fh3/ To verify if i get it right - a mix of mapping and filtering. Well @georg already solved it. Anyway, the fiddle comes without ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to extract specific columns from a matrix. Let's do that in a more abstract way: transpose the matrix, filter its rows (which are actually columns) and then transpose again:

```js
transpose = m => m[0].map((_, c) => m.map(r => r[c]))
filterColumns = (m, fn) => transpose(transpose(m).filter(fn));

matrix = [
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
    [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
]
;

result = filterColumns(matrix, col => col[0] > 10 && col[0] < 14);

document.write(result.map(r => r.join(' ')).join('<br>\n'))
```